# Variable declaration in BinarySearch

Tags: java, recursion, binary, binary-search

I am working on a java project **BinarySearch**. I'm trying to create and initialize a variable `mid` which will find out the middle value but it is giving me an error that you can't declare a variable here. I also tried it with the split declaration but it didn't work. Here is my piece of code:

```
 public static boolean binarySearch(int[] data, int target, int low, int high){
        if(low>high)
            return false;
        else
            int mid=(low + high )/2;
        if(target==data[mid]);
            return true;
        else if(target<data[mid])
            return binarySearch(data, target, low, mid - 1);
        else
            return binarySearch(data, target, mid + 1, high);


    }
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done two mistakes here.

- First you have to declare mid variable in the beginning, since it using in other scopes too (Not only in else scope).
- Second one is you have to remove the semicolon here `if(target==data[mid]);`. Since it's terminating the line.

Code after fixing those issues,

```
public static boolean binarySearch(int[] data, int target, int low, int high){
  int mid;
  if (low > high)
    return false;
  else
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
  if (target == data[mid])
    return true;
  else if (target < data[mid])
    return binarySearch(data, target, low, mid - 1);
  else
    return binarySearch(data, target, mid + 1, high);
}
```

Comment: @LaibaArooj Remove the semicolon in here too `if(target==data[mid]);` otherwise it will ignore the body of the if condition, since semicolon is terminating that line.

Comment: Hope you removed the semicolon too as I mentioned :)

Comment: I have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

when you declare a variable in a block, you cant access to it from out the block,
you should to decalre the variable out of the if and change him in the if,
then, when you access it with `target==data[mid]` the program will know where to get it.
for example:

```
public static boolean binarySearch(int[] data, int target, int low, int high){
    int mid;
    if(low>high)
        return false;
    else
        mid=(low + high )/2;
    if(target==data[mid]);
        return true;
    else if(target<data[mid])
        return binarySearch(data, target, low, mid - 1);
    else
        return binarySearch(data, target, mid + 1, high);


}
```

for more info about Variable Scope:
[Scope of Variables In Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Comment: Useful information in the link. It helped me a lot in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're declaring it inside the else, which immediately falls out of scope and the value is lost

You can avoid the issue by declaring it outside of that scope (before the if statement), or by removing the else

```
if(low>high)
    return false;
int mid=(low + high )/2;
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, it'd still be a good idea to read up on variable scoping in Timor's link, that way you can better understand how to avoid this problem in the future